# Cannot show loading image while javascript and php script are loading

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<div id="quote">
  <p>
    Click on image please.
  </p>
</div>    
<img class="post" src="positif.png" title="rate this positive" onclick="positif(this);">
```

If the image is clicked, it'll call this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function positif(obj) {
    var url = obj.parentNode.valueOf('href');
    var nama = obj.parentNode.innerText;
    alert(url);
    jq("#quote p").load("retrain/pos.php?url=" + url + "&nama=" + nama);
  }    
</script>
```

The `load` thing calls this `pos.php` script:

```
$url = $_GET["url"];
$nama = $_GET["nama"];
$nama2 = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|()'), '', $nama);
$post = '../cat/statistika/S_' . $nama2 . '.txt';

    $current = file_get_contents($url);
    if (file_get_contents($url)) {
        $current2 = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $current);
        $current3 = preg_replace('#<style(.*?)>(.*?)</style>#is', '', $current2);
        $current4 = strip_tags($current3);
        $current5 = preg_replace('/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/', '', $current4);
        file_put_contents($post, $current5);
        echo "Rated positive, Thanks for your response!";
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, connection failed. Try again later.';
    }
```

They work fine. But since I get to use `file_put_content` in there, it takes time and it won't show anything "changing" by the time the `put_content` succeeds. By extension, I have to create such as progress bar or loading image while the PHP (or javascript?) is working to finally display the `Rated positive blah2`.

I put this into the end of `positif(obj)` function:

```
jq('body').ajaxStart(function() {
jq('#loading').show();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
jq('#loading').hide();
});
```

As well as the another `div` above the `div#quote p`, with this:

```
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="loading_thing.gif" alt="Loading..." style="display: none"/>
</div>
```

Didn't work.
What did I not do here?

Comment: confused by this code:  `var url = obj.parentNode.valueOf('href');` I don't see the parent node in your HTML markup, but if the parent node is a `<a>` tag, and you have a `<div>` as a child than that is another problem altogether!

Comment: Ah, actually the `<img>` tag is inside an `<a>` tag. I didn't enclose all html code in there.

Answer (score 0):

From ajaxStart doc:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.

So try:

```
jq('document').ajaxStart(function() {
  jq('#loading, #loading-image').show();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
  jq('#loading, #loading-image').hide();
});
```

Comment: I think you need to combine with Jason's answer then ... I'll add his suggestion to my post.

Comment: I don't know, why do I keep failing on doing this?
Will you please take a look? I uploaded the screen shot. [link](http://s18.postimg.org/xwn66rbh5/SOF.png)

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to show your image placeholder as well

```
jq('body').ajaxStart(function() {
    jq('#loading, #loading-image').show();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
    jq('#loading, #loading-image').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you put this after the line `alert(url);`, it will work better:

```
jq('#loading').fadeIn(); // Just esthetic, you could use .show()
jq("#quote p").load("retrain/pos.php?url=" + url + "&nama=" + nama,
function () {
     jq('#loading').fadeOut(); // Just esthetic, you could use .hide()
});
```

Hope help you.